# How I can find all existing JDKs on my OS?

Tags: java

I wonder if it is possible to find **all** JDK's installed on my OS.

Let's assume it's one of the Debian-based distributions. I want to find any JDK in use, downloaded, or installed without being active. I want every JDK that **could** be used.

I need to include cases where somebody has changed the name the of package. I think the only solution is to search through the whole file system for specific jdk parts.

I know I can find all running java processes with `jps -m` or `ps aux | grep java`.

If I want to locate installed JDK's, I can use `update-alternatives --config java`.

But is it also possible to find JDK that were only downloaded, but not installed?

In my opinion, the most specific corner case will be when somebody unpacked a JDK and then packed it to any format (like .tar,.zip etc) without making any changes.

Comment: That probably depends on the OS.

Comment: I would like to find comprehensive solution, but just for this discussion, let's assume it's one of debian based distribution. I need to find all JDKs that can be used.

Comment: So by "downloaded but not installed" do you mean like "the `.deb` file or installer is in a users `~/Downloads` directory"? Or do you mean "just unpacked the full JDK into a subdirectory somewhere"? In either case I'm pretty sure there's no straight-forward and clean way either way. For the second one you can just brute-force search for any file named `java` that has the executable permission set. That'll find most JDKs and have rather few false positives, I assume.

Comment: A comprehensive solution to a vague question is a bit of a stretch. You should specify if you are looking for past versions, versions not yet unpacked, or both.

Comment: @AbandonedCart both. I would like to find versions that are unpacked, but also rpm or deb installation packages.

Comment: @DominikMaciejewski Are you basing this on default package names or are you trying to include alternate distributions and randomly renamed packages, as well?

Comment: A true solution vastly depends on how generalized (read: ridiculous) you want to get with this search. You could create an entire collection of known package names and binaries and search them systematically, which creates a margin of error for user naming conventions and typos. You could also opt for a vague search that will increase the margin for error exponentially because it lacks definitive parameters and will no doubt return JREs and other Java items.

Comment: @AbandonedCart I need to include case when somebody change name of package. So as I thought only solution is to find through whole file system for specific jdk parts.

Comment: @DominikMaciejewski You would have better luck compiling a full list of every checksum for every JDK package and binary that ever existed and then attempting to verify every file on the filesystem, which still presents a margin of error for partial downloads and missing files.

Comment: @AbandonedCart Yup, Your right. Real question is what can I do with rpm's or exe files. Will the solution with checksum work here?

Comment: @DominikMaciejewski Perhaps you should clarify your question.

Comment: True, my question wasn't clear. In my opinion the most specific corner case will be when somebody will unpack JDK and then pack it back to any format (like .tar,.zip etc) without making any change will the checksum (to native version) works here? Ofc I would compare native zip - repacked zip, native tar - repacked tar, not native zip - repacked tar.

Comment: I didn't see that you were asking about the checksum, but I have no intention of attempting to provide a complete method as a comment and have concerns that the only reasonable purpose for such a request would be malicious.

Comment: Thanks for edit, I didn't realize that You were talking about main post not comment. You can be sure that I didn't do it on purpose.

Answer (score 3):

A quick and dirty way to find all JDK folders, wherever they might be, would be to just search for the file `javac`, which would be present in the `bin/` folder of any JDK.  On Linux, you may try from root:

```
sudo find . -name 'javac'
```

This approach should only find JDK, and not JRE, the latter which doesn't have compile capabilities.  You would follow a similar process on other OS, such as Windows.

Comment: I'd guess that if they are running as a non-root user they'd only be interested in finding JDKs visible by that non-root user, so personally I'd drop the `sudo`.

Comment: Yup this is one of solutions, but this one would not work for packed JDKs.

Comment: Given the nature of the question, `/` may be more appropriate, albeit lengthy. Since you are going to need to start in the root folder to find **everything**, there is no reason to add the additional step of changing to that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following on the command-line:

```
which java
```

Comment: That returns the currently installed Java binary. That is the one thing **not** being requested.